# Image display by SQL command at c# , asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlcommand

What is wrong with my code? why the images not shown? i need to assign that method at the asp:image ? if yes - how ?

```
public int bla()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:**.****;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=False;");
    string commandtext = "SELECT Minbuy FROM items";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
    connection.Open();
    int itemsMin = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    string commandtext2 = "SELECT purchaseid FROM purchase";
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandtext2, connection);
    int purchase = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();

    if (itemsMin >= purchase)
        image3.Visible = true;
    else
        image4.Visible = true;

    connection.Close();



    return itemsMin;




}
```

the images at the aspx file:

```
     <asp:Image ID="image3"  runat="server" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/images/V.png" />

     <asp:Image ID="image4"  runat="server" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/images/X.png" />
```

Comment: When is this code started? With pressing a button? Or load event,... (or other)

Comment: And are the url's from the images correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. maybe the whole code is wrong (i don't get errors). what i'm trying to do is to write IF statement on sql table on c# codebhind.. but i dont know how to do that, and if my code is the right way.

Comment: They are 2 different tables on the same database.

Comment: "SELECT Minbuy FROM items", did u forgot adding a where clause?? did u try executing the query in sql mgmt studio? I believe the query should return only one record as you are using Executescalar, Cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't this be: SELECT count(purchaseid) FROM purchase ????

Comment: are you getting exception,you should'nt use executescaler for a query returns more than one row and column ,for sucha query use dataadapter anddataset or datareader

Comment: I've changed that to SELECT count(...) and no change...same result.

Comment: also check if the images images/V.png and images/x.png exist in the images directory

Comment: Bside, try "SELECT count(purchaseid) FROM purchase" and the other: "SELECT count(Minbuy) FROM items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to say without knowing what the data is!

A wild guess would be that an exception is thrown before the line `if (itemsMin >= purchase)`.

My first step would be to log the output of each sql statement, and also add logging if an exception is thrown in a `try` `catch` `finally` block.

For example:

```
    public int bla()
    {
        int itemsMin = -1;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:**.****;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=False;");
            string commandtext = "SELECT Minbuy FROM items";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
            connection.Open();
            itemsMin = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            string commandtext2 = "SELECT purchaseid FROM purchase";
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandtext2, connection);
            int purchase = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();

            if (itemsMin >= purchase)
                image3.Visible = true;
            else
                image4.Visible = true;

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return itemsMin;
    }
```

Comment: I wrote this code without trully knowladge. as you can see i'm trying to write IF staetment on SQL tables at c#... and i don't know how to do that...

Comment: I will be glad if you can give me an example for if statement on sql tables (2 different tables on the same database... let's call for one table : bla and for the second bla2 ... i need to chek one column at bla against one column at bla2.

Comment: You dont think that i need to assign this method at the image:asp ? maybe ondatatbinding event?

Comment: Is there more than one item in each table?

Comment: Yes, and more than one purchaseid each table.

Comment: In that case you need to add WHERE clauses to each SELECT statement (as @NitinJS noted), because ExecuteScalar is intended to only return one row. In this case it will return first first row.

Comment: This is getting a bit frantic. I really think it would be instructive to watch for any exceptions, and also to step through this in the debugger. You can learn a lot that way!

Comment: Also try to perfect your queries in SQL Management Studio's "New Query" window. It will help you get the SQL syntax correct, and show you what results are being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on you're method:

```
public int bla()
{
   try{
     //your code
   }catch(Exception ex){
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      return -1;
   }
}
```

When the debugger starts, you've got an error in your code.
Hover over ex (in visual studio) to see more information about the error

Comment: Hi, thank you. what i need to write on the ex ? i got error on the VWD : The variable 'ex'  is decleard but never used...

Comment: anyway... i wrote what you gave me here and i got on the page error:
Compiler Error Message: CS0161: 'DMasterPage.bla()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: In catch block write: Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); return 0;

Comment: I've edited the code. It's just because not all paths return a value.

Answer (score 0):

at firts make images visibility to true and check is it visible in normal form if its is ,make visibility to true by hard coding not by select from sql,and if this step passed may be the sql returns bad value

Comment: I've triyed to do int a = 5 int b = 6 ... if (a<b) imag3.Visble = true ... and yep, the image display. so the problem is on the sql command... the question how to fix that...

Comment: put a breakpoint on start of function and check variables value step by step